# Django Mongodb ListField not saving or updating

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, pymongo

I am starting to create a webapp using Django and MongoDB. Everything is working fine when I create a model and save it into the Database. Now, I do a "Class.objects.get()" to get the object I need from my DB and I have one field called "media" which is a ListField(). I had tried doing either:

```
Concert.media.append(list)
```

or

```
Concert.media.extend(list)
```

and then

```
Concert.save()
```

This is my "Concert" object in my models.py:

```
class Concert(models.Model):
main_artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
concert_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
openers = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Opener'))
concert_date = models.DateField()
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
media = ListField()
```

And when I go to see the results in does not update the object. No values where saved. If someone can help me I going to give a super cyber fist bump.

Answer (score 1):

`Concert` is a class, not an instance. You can't save a class. You need to make an instance of the class and save that. Something like

```
c = Concert()
c.media.append(list)
c.save()
```

(btw, just as a note, `list` is a bad variable name because list is a type in python. Never use types as variable names (though everyone is guilty of this at one point or another, including me.))

Comment: Sorry, i did a typo with that, I have just exactly as you have it. And it's weird because it is not saving at all.

Comment: In that case, please post your class def and your code around the `Class.objects.get()` you reference.

Comment: also, how are you inspecting the object post-save?

Comment: I am looking in the MongoDB shell to see if the object was modified. I  uploaded how my "Concert" object looks like.

Comment: a couple more questions: 1. I assume you're not overriding `save()`? 2. is there something already in media when you're doing this? If not, what is the value of media? I'm wondering if it's initialized to `None` instead of `[]`, and therefore can't be appended to, but I would also expect if that were the case you'd get an error (you aren't getting any errors you're not telling us, are you?)

Comment: I am not getting errors, that's the thing, nothing is blowing up. I am not overriding `save()` also. "media" it's initialized at `[]`.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, maybe I am overriding it, check this out, sorry for this. `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  if not self.concert_id:
   # Newly created object, so set slug
   self.slug = slugify(self.main_artist)
   super(Concert, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Do you think I am forgetting something here?

Comment: I think I had found the problem, I had that `super(Concert,self).save(*args, **kwargs)` indented inside the "if" statement. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: ah, yup, that would do it. In the future, post that in the question itself, as I probably would have caught it if it was formatted properly

Comment: Sorry, thanks a lot, I am newbie so that's a great suggestion for next time.